# DataTables Second Header Row for Filtering

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table, datatables

I am using the code from [Individual Column Searching](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) to add Select fields in the footer of every column to allow for filtering of the corresponding column.

I want to have this be moved to the top to be below the header field and the columns. I added a second header row and replaced `.appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )` with `.appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )`

The problem is that when I call `$(column.header()).empty()`, header() is the bottom header row. Is there a way to have the main header row be the top header row and have the multi filter select be the row right below it?

Here is what it looks like. I cannot even click the select dropdown because it just sorts the column field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick probably work for you.

Add following css to your code :

```
 tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

And change your code little bit :

Add `<tfoot>` next to your `<thead>` and above `<tbody>` as i did in one of [myfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/ehhfsrfq/760/), and your problem resolved.

Comment: That is actually a really clever solution!